# How to list items in a layouts side by side per row - android

Tags: android-layout, listview

Help me to understand the layout which can list items side by side and scrollable.

> For example

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Button02" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Button03" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        >
</LinearLayout>
```

The above example will list only two items side by side but it wont overflow so in my situation i don't know how may items the app will pull from the server but these items must overflow and show only two items per row.

Please help am just new to android so i couldn't make it.

Comment: which adapter you used?

Comment: I haven't choose any adapter cos i don't know how to do this, am only familiar with listview

Comment: What familiar? First You need to learn about listview and it's type of  adapters.

Comment: its part of listview?

Comment: You mean i can do this with listview?, share the adapter sample

Comment: No, You must have knowledge of type of adapters and its usage